# Moon is receding from Earth approximately 4cm per year

Tags: orbital-motion, earth, celestial-mechanics, moon, distance

According to the theory of relativity the universe is styled as a fabric which is depressed by a large mass and a moon, still following a straight path ever 'curves inward' toward the large mass.
Now I have read recently that the Moon is receding from Earth approximately 4cm per year!
Please can someone provide me with a plausible explanation for this apparent anomaly?

Comment: I'm not  presently conversant in GR, but as I recall the image of "a fabric depressed by a large mass" is an oversimplification of GR. But I'm still learning and will be following the responses to your post.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Maybe moon is inching away from certain earthling like Donald or Greta, or both? Jesting aside, it's just the plain old tidal effect.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for the answer? E.g. https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-12311119

Comment: what is the anomaly?

Comment: @MadMax it is certainly both lol

Answer (score 1):

Tidal acceleration, often referred to as tidal drag, boosts the moon's orbit. This causes it to move farther out from Earth. here is some good information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration

Answer (score 1):

Fabric being depressed by a mass is simply a visualization/metaphor that is used in popular "explanations" of general relativity. It's not part of the actual theory. I find it a bit circular; the reason it makes sense that larger masses would depress the fabric more than smaller ones is because larger masses have more weight, but weight comes from gravity, so that's explaining gravity in terms of gravity.

There also seem to be two versions of this. In both, the curvature is caused by the weight of the masses, but in one the effect of the depressions is to cause other objects to fall into the depression, which is further circular (since gravity is what causes them to fall into the depression, this is even more explaining gravity in terms of gravity).

But presumably the point, which often gets lost in many retellings of this analogy, is that masses curve spacetime, and what looks like curved paths from outside are straight within the space. So it's not that objects *fall* into the depressions, but that they take paths that are straight within the fabric's geometry, but look curved, and we interpret that curving as the object being acted on by a force. But spacetime is 4D, and the fabric is 2D, so it's easy for this analogy to get lost. In particular, while gravity causes objects initially "at rest" to begin moving, the fabric deflects the path only of moving objects. In 4D, of course, every object is moving through time, so gravity affects the path of every object.

As for the moon, the change in distance is caused not just by point mass type gravity, but the interaction between gravity and rotation. Tides on the Earth are caused by the moon, and the energy involved in tides has to come from somewhere, and that somewhere is the moon's kinetic energy. This slows the moon down that in a manner that the fabric analogy doesn't explain very well, and as the moon slows down, it moves to a more distant orbit.

Comment: Nice question except for the end. Likely you wanted to say that Moon speeds up its orbital velocity.

Comment: I don't know of a single person, ever, who has been helped by that analogy!  It is an awful combination of misdirection and technobabble.  IMO of course ;)